# Android AlarmManager.setExact() not firing

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am having trouble with using Alarm Manager to fire a pending intent in the future. I have been at it for hours, and do not understand what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This works, sending a broadcast immedietely:

```
_context.startService(notificationIntent);
```

This works, sending a broadcast in ~30 seconds:

```
if (mgr != null) 
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 30000, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingNotificationIntent);
```

This works, sending a broadcast in ~30 seconds:

```
if (mgr != null) 
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 30000, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingNotificationIntent);
```

But for some unknown reason, doing this fails. The broadcast is never triggered. When I take System.currentTimeMillis(), and subtract it from my trigger...it shows that the trigger is indeed in the future:

```
if (mgr != null) 
mgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, trigger, pendingNotificationIntent);
```

I am printing my variable 'trigger' (type long) to console, and it is definitely a valid time (according to epochconverter.com). The value it is printing currently (just for reference) is 1521144300000, which elapsed a few minutes ago..never having fired my alarm;

Here is most of the setup:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(_context, com.example.example.NotificationReceiver.class)
                            .setAction(ACTION_SHOW_NOTIFICATION)
                            .putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TITLE, _title)
                            .putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_BODY, newBody)
                            .putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TRIGGER_TIME, trigger);


                    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(_context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    Log.d(TAG, "trigger time: " + trigger);

                    if (mgr != null) mgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, trigger, pendingNotificationIntent);
```

I receive the trigger time from the back-end, which appears correct in every response.

This also never fires:

```
if (mgr != null) mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, trigger, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingNotificationIntent);
```

Comment: It is like it doesnt like my trigger time...but I know it is in milliseconds, and it is in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some considerations depending in the Android version in which you are testing the alarm, but if you are testing for Android 6 or later then try the next code:

```
// Init the Alarm Manager.
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 

// Setting the PendingIntent to be fired when alarm triggers.
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), YourService.class);
PendingIntent pendingServiceIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, serviceIntent, 0);

// Set the alarm for the next seconds.  
alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + seconds * 1000, pendingServiceIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you for our input!

I tried your suggestion, and it still is not firing.

I printed out to the console, the epoch time I want to use...and then the seconds I converted it to so that I could use your example:
Scheduling notification at (epoch)1521154500000.  Seconds until trigger: 38

Comment: I waited 2 minutes, and my receiver did not receive the broadcast. It is frustrating that I can send immediately, but not with AlarmManager.

Comment: I also changed .getService to .getBroadcast, for my use case.

Comment: Can you try to make a simple Service (or IntentService will be better) that broadcast a message to your receiver? The receiver must detect when that service send that message. The receiver (as long as I remember) was like a passive "service" which hears all the broadcast messages filtered by the intent-filter specified in the AndroidManifest.xml. I dont think that must be put in the PendingIntent that fires each N seconds.

Comment: I was making a completely rookie mistake my friend. I was scheduling this alarm within a loop, each iteration with a new trigger time....but same request id. Incrementing the id resolved the issue. I greatly appreciate your input.

Comment: Sure. Glad to help.